subtraction via recursion within a range of numbers (java)
I’m trying to practice understanding recursion in java and this code keeps giving me an unexpected output. I want to subtract all numbers between a user submitted range.
For example, if the user inputs 1 and 3 it should output -4 (1-2-3=-4) however I keep getting a different result.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class recursionTest {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     int input1;
     int input2;


     System.out.println("Please input lower value: ");
     Scanner inputOneTaker = new Scanner(System.in);
     input1 = inputOneTaker.nextInt();
     System.out.println("Please input higher value: ");
     Scanner inputTwoTaker = new Scanner(System.in);
     input2 = inputTwoTaker.nextInt();



        int result = sum(input1,input2);
                System.out.println(result);
    }

        public static int sum ( int x, int y)
        {
        if (x < y) {
            return x - sum(x+1,y);

        }
        else {
            return y;
        }


        }
    }

For example, if the user inputs 1 and 3 it should output -4 (1-2-3=-4) however i keep getting a different result.

sum(3,3) = 3;
sum(2,3) = 2 - sum(3,3) = 2 - 3 = -1;
sum(1,3) = 1- sum(2,3) = 1 - (-1) = 1+1 = 2;
This is what your logic is doing.

so my intent is if the user enters 1 and 3 you get 1- sum(2,3) (2 is less than three so repeat) 1-2-sum(3,3) 3 is not less than 3 so go to else, which returns 3) 1-2-3 output-4 what do i need to change to get that logic?

@KanagawaPunk you want just the first number to be as given and sum the negative of remaining number?

well i probably misunderstand whats happening but heres how i imagine it:
user enters 1 for x and 3 for y--- the if loop says return x -sum(x+1, 3)--- shouldnt that mean the x becomes one? like 1- sum(1+2, 3)--- now x is 2 so 1-2-sum(2+1,3)--- this triggers the else so sum becomes y (which is 3)--- so shouldnt it come out as 1-2-3?

if its addition, yes. But its subtraction. -(-) becomes +.

Look at it this way instead: sum(1,3) = 1 - sum(2,3) -> sum(2,3) = 2 - sum(3,3) -> sum(3,3) = 3. If you replace the value of sum(2,3) with it's result, which is -1, you can see that you get sum(1,3) = 1 - (-1) = 2

you want 1 - 2 - 3 but are calculating 1 - (2 - 3) (or for 1 to 4: 1 - (2 - (3 - 4))) - the main problem is that the first number is not negative but all others are, and using the - operator twice is actually doing a +

You can go with @authorizeduser answer if you can skip out input1 from the recursion method.
This will go in the opposite direction.
For (1,3) -> -3 + (-2 + (1)) - > -3 -2 +1 = -4.
For (1,4) -> -4 + (-3 + (-2 + (1))) - > -4 -3 -2 +1 = -8.
public static int sum ( int x, int y)
{
    if(x == y) {
        return x;
    }
    return -y + sum(x,y-1);
}


ok, thank you, going through this it makes sense. i need to work on my mathematical thinking/logic/problem solving ability because i dont think i would have arrived at this naturally.

From your question, my understanding is that you want to subtract from input1, the remaining numbers up to input2. because you mentioned for input1 = 1 and input2 = 3, you want -4 which is 1 - 2 - 3.
If you think carefully, you can just add the remaining numbers and subtract it from the input1. which is very simple.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int input1 = 1;
    int input2 = 4;
    int resSum = sum(input1+1, input2);
    System.out.println(input1 - resSum);
}
    
public static int sum(int a, int b) {
    if(a <= b) {
        return a + sum(a+1, b);
    } 
    return 0;
}

I think the code is pretty self explanatory. It is just adding all the numbers until a > b then we return 0.

ok, thank you, going through this it makes sense. i need to work on my mathematical thinking/logic/problem solving ability because i dont think i would have arrived at this naturally. –
